# Proving a given vector to be a four-vector

Tags: special-relativity, waves, inertial-frames, vectors

How to prove that
$$k=(\frac{\omega}{c}  , \vec{k})$$
is a four-vector?

Where $\omega$ is the frequency and $\vec{k}$ is a wave vector.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Also: What do you know? Multilinear algebra?
tensorcalculus? Every 4 component vector can be a four-vector...

Comment: @NathanaelNoir is that true? A four vector is something whose components transform in a particular way

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A four-vector is an element of a four-dimensional vector space considered as a representation space of the standard representation of the Lorentz group, the $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ representation. Therefore a four-vector transform in a specific way under Lorentz transformation.

Answer (score 1):

We know, the four-position
$$x^\mu=(ct,\vec{r})$$
is a four-vector.
We also know, for a plane wave its phase at any certain point in spacetime
$$\phi=-\omega t+\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r},$$
must be a four-scalar (i.e. the same value in every reference frame).
To convince yourself about this, consider a scalar plane wave like
$$\psi(t,\vec{r})=A\cos(-\omega t+\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r})$$
and a particular point-like event (like an atom emitting an
$\alpha$ particle at a certain position and time).
Then all observers (regardless which reference frame they use)
can agree on whether this event happened at a $\psi$-wave crest
(i.e. $\phi=0$), at a $\psi$-wave trough (i.e. $\phi=180°$),
or at a certain phase $\phi$ in between.

Let us rewrite this phase:
$$\begin{align}
\phi&=-\omega t+\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r} \\
&=-\left(\frac{\omega}{c},-\vec{k}\right)\cdot(ct,\vec{r})
  && \text{use }x^\mu=(ct,\vec{r})
    \text{ and define } k_\mu=\left(\frac{\omega}{c},-\vec{k}\right) \\
&= -k_\mu x^\mu
\end{align}$$

The left side ($\phi$) of this equation is a four-scalar, so the
expression on the right side ($-k_\mu x^\mu$) must be a four-scalar too.
This means, since $x^\mu$ is a four-vector, $k_\mu$ must also be
a four-vector to make their product a four-scalar.
So we found
$$k_\mu=\left(\frac{\omega}{c},-\vec{k}\right)$$
is a covariant (i.e. lower index) four-vector.
And the corresponding contravariant (i.e. upper index) four-vector is
$$k^\mu=\left(\frac{\omega}{c},\vec{k}\right).$$

Comment: Correct, but to complete the proof, I suggest, you would need to give an argument that the phase $\phi$ is Lorentz-invariant (without assuming that $k^\mu$ is a 4-vector, so as to avoid circularity).

Comment: @AndrewSteane A valid point. I have tried to add a convincing argument for this.